# How big in terms of the galaxy is hundreds of star systems?

Tags: worldbuilding-process

As the title states, how much of our galaxy are we referring to if we speak of a portion "hundreds of star systems" in size?  The Orion Arm?  The whole quadrant?

Comment: You might have been better off posting this on [Astronomy.se]. But, I already posted the answer too.

Comment: @JDługosz [Please don't answer and VTC the same question](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/3515/6986).

Comment: Well, I ask for purposes of world-building.  I got what I needed, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tiny speck.  Maybe 25 light years in radius around us?

See [*Atlas of the Universe*](http://www.atlasoftheuniverse.com): there are [109 within 20 light years](http://www.atlasoftheuniverse.com/nearstar.html). So use that as an average density, and 40 ly radius would have about 900.  Anywhere between 20 and 40 would contain “hundreds”.

Answer (score 1):

There are currently [56 known stars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_nearest_stars_and_brown_dwarfs) withing 17 light-years from Earth. The [Milky Way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milky_Way) contains 100 to 400 billion stars; 100 stars is 1 billionth of our galaxy.

Answer (score 0):

It's a house, a small one, on a very small street of a very small village. In a scale of our stellar system. Now you can imagine the scale.